# Out of Stock Products Displaying on front-end when told not to!

Tags: configuration, inventory, out-of-stock

just a quick one. Using Magento 2.3.2

I have "**Display out of stock products**" switched to "**No**" in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory, but my storefront still displays all the O.O.S. products. I have cleared caches, flushed caches, re-indexed, re-deployed, but still, there they are. I would like them to go away now. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Question: What do you mean by "still displays"? My understanding is that these items should disappear from search and browse but that the product pages will still "work" (not give a 404 not found error).

Comment: OK. They are still listed on category pages in the grid/list.